# XSLT: Selective Node Handling

Tags: xslt

I have the following xsd snippet:

```
<xs:complexType name="HighSchoolType">
  <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="OrganizationName" type="core:OrganizationNameType"/>
      <xs:group ref="core:OrganizationIDGroup" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I want to handle xs:element tags differently than xs:group tags, while completely ignoring xs:annotation and xs:restriction tags.  When I have an:

- xs:element tag, I want to copy it.
- xs:group tag, I want the output to contain the children of the xs:group tags'  tag.
- Any other tag can be ignored, I don't want it in my output

I've been trying to use:

```
<xsl:template match="xs:complexType">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="*[self::xs:element]|@*">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="*[self::xs:group]|@*">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </xsl:when>             
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't understand why this:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::xs:annotation or self::xs:restriction)]|@*"/>
```

...will exclude xs:annotation & xs:restriction nodes while

```
<xsl:when test="*[self::xs:element]|@*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:when>
```

...returns everything while:

```
<xsl:when test="*[self::xs:group]|@*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:when>
```

...never triggers:

```
<xsl:variable name="core" select="document('CoreMain_v1.4.0.xsd')" />
<xsl:variable name="AcRec" select="document('AcademicRecord_v1.3.0.xsd')" />

<xsl:template match="xs:group[@ref]">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="substring-after(@ref, ':')" />

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="substring-before(@ref, ':') = 'AcRec'">             
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$AcRec//*[@name=$name]" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="substring-before(@ref, ':') = 'core'">              
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$core//*[@name=$name]" />
        </xsl:when>             
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xs:group[@name]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(self::xs:annotation|self::xs:restriction)]|@*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed:

```
<xsl:template match="xs:complexType">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="*[self::xs:element]|@*">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="*[self::xs:group]|@*">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                    </xsl:when>                             
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

...into:

```
<xsl:template match="xs:complexType">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
      <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xs:sequence">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::xs:element">
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="self::xs:group">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:when>                 
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```